# What is the optimal algorithm to optimize reservations for bowling lanes

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am looking for advice on optimization algorithm for guest reservations. Context: I am working at an entertainment company (think bowling venue) which has n lanes in each venue. Guests can book a reservation for precisely two hours and can only stay in one lane (same as bowling example). Given x reservations for a given day, I need to reshuffle the reservations so that the dead time (time <2hrs between reservations) was minimized and utilization of each bay (total reservation time / total open time) was maximized. So I need to stack reservations vertically first, then if not possible - horizontally.

I developed a naive greedy solution, that grabs one reservation at a time and finds the next best slot, and it's already working pretty good, but I was thinking about how to improve it. I would imagine real optimization based on Gradient Descent could work much better. I coded this data as columns are lanes, rows are 15 min chunks of time (10:00, 10:15, etc) and reservations are coded as 1, blocked time (where you can't slot anything) as 9, cleaning time (associates need to clean for 15min after reservation is over) as 2, open time coded as zero. (example on screenshot)

My data is miniscule, they only have max 200 reservations per day, so computation is not a big deal. Even something at O(N^2) will be milliseconds fast.
Please suggest some articles, or if someone developed something similar in the past, would appreciate help. Could PuLP help with this? I am just not sure how to use it on my dataset.
[image]

Comment: Modeling this as a MIP would give you the optimal solution (which then cannot be improved by definition). And modeling/solving MIPs can indeed be done using PuLP. But there are other frameworks as well and most MIP solvers offer direct Python interfaces as well.
Given that this is a scheduling problem, it may also be useful to consider software that is dedicated to scheduling problems.

Comment: Still relevant? If so, please show sample data/ random data to make an solution

Comment: @DanielJunglas thank you. yeah it's not a trivial stuff looks like. I will try to look into solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DanielJunglas said, using PuLP will give you an optimal solution, and you should be able to model this problem reasonably simply as a mixed-integer or possibly pure binary integer program. Just be aware that these solvers work very differently to traditional algorithms, and so there are a variety of influences on performance. For example, this problem has a lot of symmetry (different solutions with the same objective value) which could really hurt solve times.

A linear program is formulated as a set of variables, a set of constraints on the values of those variables, and an objective function based on those variables that we are trying to max/min. The solver will find the solution (the values of the variables) that meet the constraints with the largest/smallest objective value. PuLP lets you write the formulation in a fairly user-friendly way, and then lets you call an open source solver to solve it.

Here's an example BIP formulation:

```
from pulp import *
import random

prob = LpProblem("Prob1", LpMinimize)

# Define the input parameters (randomly generated)
hours = 10
resLenInts = 8 # 2 hours in 15 min intervals
numres = 50
resStartTimes = {x:random.randint(0,hours*4 - 2*4 - 1) for x in range(numres)} #id:starttime dict
resLengths = {x:8 for x in range(numres)} # Res length in intervals
cleanTime = 1
T = range(hours*4)
lanes = range(0,40)

# Create our variables
X = LpVariable.dicts("resInLane", (resStartTimes.keys(), lanes), cat=LpBinary) # 1 if reservation r uses lane l, 0 otherwise

Y = LpVariable.dicts("laneEmpty", (lanes), cat=LpBinary) # 1 if a lane l has no reservations, 0 otherwise

# Perturbing the objective function to try and break some symmetry
coeffs = {r:{l:random.random()*0.00001 for l in lanes} for r in resStartTimes}

# Objective function, the function we are trying to minimize the value of
# This should be a pure statement, not an equation (not an equality/inequality)
prob += - lpSum(Y[l] for l in lanes) - lpSum(Y[l]*((len(lanes)-l)/len(lanes)) for l in lanes) - lpSum(X[r][l]*coeffs[r][l] for r in resStartTimes for l in lanes), "Maximize empty lanes"

## Constraints
# These are the restrictions on which solutions are valid

# Reservation can only use one lane
for r in resStartTimes.keys():
    prob += lpSum(X[r][l] for l in lanes) == 1

# Reservations cannot overlap
for r1 in resStartTimes.keys():
    for r2 in resStartTimes.keys():
        if r1 != r2:
            if resStartTimes[r1] < resStartTimes[r2]:
                if resStartTimes[r1] + resLengths[r1] + cleanTime > resStartTimes[r2]:
                    for l in lanes:
                        prob += X[r1][l] + X[r2][l] <= 1
            elif resStartTimes[r2] < resStartTimes[r1]:
                if resStartTimes[r2] + resLengths[r2] + cleanTime > resStartTimes[r1]:
                    for l in lanes:
                        prob += lpSum(X[r1][l] + X[r2][l]) <= 1    
            else:
                for l in lanes:
                    prob += lpSum(X[r1][l] + X[r2][l]) <= 1                  

# Restricts Y so that it represents what we want
# Ie. 1 if a lane has no reservations, 0 otherwise
for l in lanes:
    prob += lpSum(X[r][l] for r in resStartTimes.keys()) - 0.1 <= 9999*(1 - Y[l])
    prob += 0.1 - lpSum(X[r][l] for r in resStartTimes.keys()) <= 9999*Y[l]

prob.X = X
prob.Y = Y

# Solve the problem using CBC, stopping early when we get within 50% of the theoretical best
prob.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=True, fracGap=0.5))

# Print the solution
laneslist = [f'{lane} '.zfill(3) for lane in lanes]
print(f"\t {''.join(laneslist)}")
for t in range(hours*4):
    temp = [[f'{r} '.zfill(3) if (prob.X[r][l].varValue == 1 and t in range(resStartTimes[r], resStartTimes[r] + resLengths[r])) else '' for r in resStartTimes.keys()] for l in lanes]
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        tempstr = ""
        for j in range(len(temp[i])):
            tempstr += temp[i][j]
        temp[i] = tempstr
    temp = [x if x != '' else '   ' for x in temp]
    print(f"{t} \t {''.join(temp)}")
```

This will probably struggle to do more than 50 reservations 50 lanes or so though, and it only indirectly minimizes dead time by maximizing the utilization of used lanes. In a way the problem is almost too unconstrained for linear programming to be effective. Something simple like breaking the problem up into subproblems (sets of reservations and lanes) and then combining them back together could be a good way to easily improve the performance, and since the lanes and reservations are independent it should work quite well.

Outside of PuLP, you could try a heuristic like one of the innumerable variations of genetic algorithms (e.g. simulated annealing, particle swarm). These won't guarantee optimality but could be superior in performance vs time compared with a LP due to the specific problem structure. A dedicated scheduling solver would probably give you the best results, as they will take advantage of all the possible techniques, but I'm not sure what the free/open-source options are like.

Some other notes:

- Problem formulation is crucial for LP solving, so a good formulation is the most effective way to get good performance. If you go with PuLP, spend some time thinking about the best way to represent the problem: what are the variables, the constraints, the objective.
- Take advantage of the solver log to see where the solver is struggling. [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257713115_Practical_guidelines_for_solving_difficult_mixed_integer_linear_programs) is a good description of some of the common issues and possible solutions.

Hopefully this helps you figure out if PuLP is a good choice for you, and if so maybe it helps get you started. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for such detailed answer. I haven't done much optimization but the way you described it - makes perfect sense